# SQL Query to include order of item in select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table

| order id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 5 | A |
| 3 | B |

I need to write a select query to get following output:

| order id | item | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 5 | A | 2 |
| 1 | B | 1 |
| 3 | B | 2 |

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What's the business logic you are applying here? If you don't explain why the order should be like your desired output, you might end up with a solution that happens to work with your 4 sample rows, but that generates undesired output in the real world.

Comment: `[order] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY [order id])` ... `ORDER BY item, [order];`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() rank function and write query like this:

```
create table orders
(
    order_id int,
    item nvarchar(max)
)

insert into orders values(1,'A');
insert into orders values(1,'B');
insert into orders values(5,'A');
insert into orders values(3,'B');


SELECT order_id, item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY item ORDER BY item ASC, order_id ASC) as [order] 
FROM ORDERS
order by  item asc, order_id asc
```

Check the ranking functions: https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-sql-rank-functions/

Comment: Ordering by the thing you're partitioning on doesn't accomplish anything deterministic, don't you want the row number to be applied using `order by order_id`?